# How to find string in an array in O(1)

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm studying for future interviews and I wanted to know something.
I have an array of six strings, and I want to know if there is some way
to find one of them in O(1) like a Hash table.
For example, suppose that we have the following strings in advance.

```
char* massageOp[6] = {"SIL","TAG","SILA","TAGS","AVS", "AVST"};
```

Now the user gives me one string, any string, and I want to know If I can find the string in my array, or no, in O(1). Is there any way to do this, or I need to pass through all the array to find it out?
Thanks.

Comment: Presumably in the general case, you have more than 6 strings?  Otherwise talking about big-O notation is somewhat meaningless.  Also, do you mean O(1) in the number of strings, or in the length of the input string?

Comment: No - this problem is exactly what a hashtable is for.

Comment: Look up how hash tables work.  Yes, a properly created hash table to place your array in will give you O(1) access in your case.

Comment: but it will search in the hash, not in your *array*. lot of confusion here.

Comment: O(1) with respect to what? The length of the string or the size of the array?

Comment: Thank you all, but how can I implement a Hash table for strings? I know how to this in case of integers..

Comment: @yi_H: Hashing lets you construct sets as well as tables.

Comment: @Inerdia with respect to the size of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you define O(1) just as Oli mentioned. If you want an EXPECTED O(1) (recall that hash-table may have collisions and it's difficult to estimate a worst-case complexity) time complexity in the number of strings. It would be easy to use some good string hashing algorithms to solve the problem, for example, we may use ELFHash:

```
int ELFhash(char* key, long M) {
  unsigned long h = 0;
  while(*key) {
    h = (h << 4) + *key++;
    unsigned long g = h & 0xF0000000L;
    if (g) h ^= g >> 24;
    h &= ~g;
  }
  return h % M;
}
```

Using this ELFHash function with your string as "key" and a large prime number as "M", you can get an integer value which is the hash value of your string. You can also use some other string hashing functions and you can find some discussions here: [Hashing Tutorial](http://research.cs.vt.edu/AVresearch/hashing/strings.php)

Comment: The OP stated that the strings are known in advanced, as such you can create a prefect hash function.

Comment: @Wiz: Actually reading his problem formulation carefully again, it seems not that well-defined. He mentioned that he has an array of "six strings", well, if that value of "six" is fixed. Then no matter what kind of algorithm you are using to search whether a string exists in that array with size 6, it would still be an O(1)-algorithm......

Comment: @derekhh I'm going to ask a question you will see it as a poor one,  but how can I create a prefect hash function in case the strings are known in advanced? is there any universal way? thanks

Comment: @OfirAn: No, that's a very good question. I'll try to explain my thoughts. Speaking of a "perfect" hash function, actually it is just a hash function that will not have any collision on the input strings you have. Generally speaking, if you are having only six strings, using any classic hashing functions for strings, the chances of having collisions is very very rare.

Comment: @OfirAN:  However, you may have noticed that some classic string hashing functions are quite complicated and may require more operation cycles than some "simple" ones, e.g. just take the sum of the characters and then get the modulus of a large prime. These functions may not work well when there are a large number of strings since the probability of collision is much higher than the classic ones, however, applying such functions on a range of six strings would usually give you good results and no collision, hence a perfect hash function for this case as well.

Comment: @derekhh What do you mean in "sum of the characters" ?  the number of characters in each string?

Comment: @OfirAN: something like the sum of the ASCII code of all the characters? e.g. for "SIL" you can use 83 + 73 + 76 = 232

Comment: @derekhh that's exactly what I did, and now I'm checking it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you put all the elements into a hash, no, you cannot, and average case will always be O(n). If you put them into a hash you can look them up in O(1) time (slowing if your hash algorithm is poor).

Comment: Lookup in a hash table is O(1), if the hash function is poor, insertion speed becomes slow, not lookup.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: you need the hashed value for the lookup, no difference.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That depends on how collisions are handled in the hashtable implementation.

Comment: @yi_H the hash value is computed in O(1) regardless of the function.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Er? Hash table lookup is linear for a horrible hash function like h(x) = 1.

Comment: True but knowing the hashed value of the string isn't enough to see if anything is stored in that location.

Comment: @mkb That depends on how it's implemented.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: I don't know why you think I didn't know that.

Comment: I had no idea h(x)=1 can be considered a hash function.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That's not true. If multiple values are hashed to the same hash key, it will take O(m) where m is the number of entries for that hash value. This occurs when there is a collision, making overall O(n+α).

Comment: @yi_H yes, by linear I mean O(n). I mean, I guess O(1) is a horizontal line so that's linear time too :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Any function from a key to an integer can be considered a hash function.

Comment: I call it the smoking hash function. It's a hash function the way bogosort is a sorting algorithm.

Comment: @yi_H What mkb means is linear *growth* which is O(n). PS: Thanks for confirming that I'm not crazy everyone :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I removed the downvote, my bad. You learn something new every day. :D

Comment: @LuchianGrigore No worries. If you happen to have Cormen's Intro to Algorithms book take a look at the chapter on hash tables for way more info than can reasonably be given here. If you don't own it, it's a worthwhile investment for a programmer.